# How to make a register form for phpbb

Tags: php, forms, phpbb

I was wondering if anyone could help me make a register form for phpbb. I need this for a website I'm doing, which the client would like to not have 2 different accounts for the same person.

So I looked into this, and I found the function `add_user()`, but I have no idea on how to use it. I also asked on the phpbb forums, and all they did was point me at the wiki page for the function, which again didn't help me at all.

So if anyone knows anything about how to use this, or a tutorial on how to make one anything like that, help me out!

Comment: Why not look into the phpbb source and see what the function's doing? Shouldn't be too hard to extract the relevant bits, and/or figure out how to include phpbb's libraries into your app.

Comment: @Mitchel: Please put some effort in writing in correct English, using correct capitalization etc. There also is a reason people invented line breaks. Aside of being easier on the eyes, your questions will also get more answers.

Answer (score 4):

Use it like this

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);

$user_row = array(
        'username'                      => "his username",
        'user_password'                 => phpbb_hash("new_password"),
        'user_email'                    => "mail@ofuser.com",
        'group_id'                      => 2,
        'user_timezone'                 => 1,
        'user_dst'                      => 1,
        'user_lang'                     => "en",
        'user_type'                     => 0,
        'user_actkey'                   => "",
        'user_ip'                       => "",
        'user_regdate'                  => time(),
        'user_inactive_reason'          => 0,
        'user_inactive_time'            => 0,
);
user_add($user_row, $cp_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

user_add is pretty simple to use.  But before you use it, you'll want to check the validity of your input.  For example, check the user already exists.

Here's what I build.  This handles a form that submits username, email and password:

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '/forum/';

$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('');

//Do something here to retrieve get/post variables 

// Validate input
$invalid_username = validate_username($username);
$invalid_email = validate_email($email);
$invalid_password = validate_password($password);
if($invalid_username || $invalid_password || $invalid_email){ //handle error
}

//Build user_row array
$user_row = array(
    'username'              => $username,
    'user_password'         => phpbb_hash($password),
    'user_email'            => $email,
    'group_id'              => 2,
    'user_lang'             => 'en_us',
    'user_type'             => USER_NORMAL,
    'user_ip'               => $user->ip,
    'user_regdate'          => time(),
);

//register and handle error
$user_id = user_add($user_row);
if ($user_id === false){
    //handle error
}
```